# Reading string phrase and putting words in multidimensional array

Tags: c

I am trying to read a string and put each word from a phrase (string) inside a multidimensional array, the delimiter character is the space.

Some of the code seems to work, but the last word is not being stored in the array.

**input:**

> $string 1: pop pop pop pop

**output**

> pop pop pop pop
>
> Full String:pop pop pop pop
>
> 1st:pop
>
> 2nd:pop
>
> 3rd:pop
>
> 4th:
>
> number of spaces: 3

The issue seems to be in the for cycle, i should use "i<=space", but if i do this, it gives me:

**output**

> segmentation fault: 11

```
int countS (char s[]){
    int i,k;

    i=0;
    k=0;

    while(s[i]!='\0'){
        if((int) s[i]==32){
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return k;
}

int main () {
    int i, k, j, space;
    char t[100];
    printf("string 1:  \n");
    scanf("%100[0-9a-zA-Z ]", t);
    space = countS(t);
    char s[space+1][10];


    for(i=0, k=0; i<space; i++){
        j=0;
        while (t[k]!=' '){
            s[i][j]=t[k];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        k++;
        s[i][j]='\0';
    }

    printf("Full String:%s\n1st Word:%s \n2nd word:%s \n3rd word:%s \n4th Word:%s \n number of spaces: %d \n", t,s[0],s[1],s[2],s[3], countS(t));
}
```

Thank you for all the help provided!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, please read my question, i referred that problem in my post. But if i do change that it gives me an error.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, i know that it should be like that, please read my question. If i change to i<=space it gives me "segmentation error:11"

Comment: because `while (t[k]!=' '){` over run.

Comment: How's that? Sorry, can't understand the "over run" thing

Comment: Check is insufficient.  nonstop after the third space. access exceeds the valid range of the array.

Comment: try `while (t[k] && t[k]!=' '){`

Comment: Can you put that comment as an answer please? It solved the problem. 
That means the initial charge of the t array is {'s','t','r','i','n','g',0,0,0,0,0,0} and is assumed as the bool value of false, and as it reaches the "false" value?

Comment: "pop pop" means `{'p','o','p',' ','p','o','p','\0'}`. `'\0'` equal `0` and evaluate as false.

Comment: I had tried before the "t[k]!='\0'" and it didn't worked, why?

Comment: `while (t[k] && t[k]!=' '){` <=> `while (t[k]!='\0' && t[k]!=' '){` both will work. They are regarded as the same.

Comment: also `scanf("%100[0-9a-zA-Z ]", t);` change to `scanf("%99[0-9a-zA-Z ]", t);` : 99 not buffer size, read maximum number of character. reserve one for '\0'.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , Post an answer. You solved the problem! And @Skills, change `char s[space+1][10];` to `char s[space+1][100];`.